# How to adjust textview width dynamically in a tablerow

Tags: android, dynamic, textview, tablelayout

i have a simple tablelayout each table row has the following components

image view1 | Text view | Image view2 |Image View2

The text view data is provided from the database.

how to set widthof(textview) = widthof(screen)-[(widthof(imageview1)+widthof(imageview2)+widthof(imageview3)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to get the width

```
int width = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth() - (imageview2.getWidth() + 
        imageview3.getWidth());
ViewGroup.LayoutParams vp = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(width,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
textview.setLayoutParams(vp);
```